# Value sent through jQuery AJAX is always null in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a hard time passing the value of a string entered in the textbox going to the controller using AJAX. I've tried this but it didn't work.

```
<input type="text" name="refID" id="refID"><br />
<button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {
    alert("hahaha");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '@Url.Action("TransactionVerification", "Dashboard")',
      data: {
        RefID: $("#refID").val()
      },
      success: function (response) {
        $(".content").html(response);
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("Problem on uploading file");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```csharp
public async Task<ActionResult> TransactionVerification(String RefId)
{
  //some code
}
```

When I debug the value of the `RefId` in the controller is always null.

Comment: The name of client side parameter should match  In Controller, So try  `String RefID`

Comment: It worked now thanks :)